# Difference between hexadecimal values and normal types

Tags: c, hex

I am doing an assignment in c:

Basically I have a struct where it has `char` and `int` types. The assignment says that I have to fill the struct fields with some predefined values.

The thing is that those values are represented as hexadecimal values. Since I am a bit confused with hexadecimal, I would like to fill the fields with normal values.

For example an `int` filed, I would like to assign `20151` instead of `0x4EB7`.

I know it works but still I am a bit worried, is there any difference between these representations?

Comment: These are _hexadecimal integer literals_. There is no other difference to _decimal integer literals_ than the base: _hexadecmal_ is base 16, _decimal_ is base 10. Both are converted to _binary_ for the computer, so the value is actually the same: `0x12 == 18`: `1 * 16 + 2 * 1 == 1 * 10 + 8 * 1`

Comment: And for chars would it be the same as well?

Comment: @lhahn `char`s are just one-byte integers.

Comment: @Quentin: Note that a byte is not necessarily 8 bits.

Comment: @Olaf neither is a `char` :)

Comment: As you apparently have such fundamental gaps of knowledge: Either you did not listen properly when these were discussed in your lessons, or they are not that good. In any case: I strongly recommend to read a god book about programming in general and/or programming in C. The better ones treat such things in early chapters. Just asking here is actually a bad idea, as you will not get the whole picture.

Comment: @Quentin: Logic basics: (`char` <=> `byte` AND `byte` "not always 8 bits") => (`char` "not always 8 bits"). I did not criticize the prerequisite (that is clearly stated in the standard).

Comment: @Olaf I'll give you that if you insist, but I never mentioned 8 bits.

Comment: @Quentin: Sorry, I did not state this clear enough. It was more of an addition, no critique. Most people tend to associate `byte` with 8 bits, which is simply not true.

Comment: @Olaf oh. Indeed, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are 2 ways of expressing the same thing; you can use whichever makes the most sense.